# update combo box values in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Hi i have a combo box in a form (unbound form). The user has to enter some data, select a value from a combo box, push Save button, and then keep entering data until all the values from the combo are done. My combo has the **RowSource Property** set to a SELECT statement that retrieves all the data all the time. What i want: when the user selects a value from the combo and push the Save button the selected value gets removed from the combo. Example:

The combo has two values: -25 to 35 years
                          -36 to 45 years

The user selects a value :-36 to 45 years, enter other data and push Save button

As a result the combo should only have one option: -25 to 35 years

(after that it keeps on the same form, to enter data until no available options on combo)

Comment: Please display your select statement? we can help you write the where clause!

Comment: are the values "saved" to a table?

Answer (score 0):

**Form:** create a form with text box where you save select value with comma sparated string `exmaple: "1","2","3"` when you press the save button

Use the following SQL for the Dropdown, which will eliminate the selected value from the drop down

**SQL query**

```
SELECT Table1.Value
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Value) Not In ([Forms]![Form1]![Text0])));
```

**Table:**

```
table1
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Result in drop down for above sql senerio**

```
Result
4
5
6
```